# Magento 1.9: I need to create custom theme in enterprise edition

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, custom-theme

I need to create custom theme in enterprise edition. 
Anyone have solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a new design package, in both `design` and `skin` folders.

Let’s call it `MyPackage`.

In your design package, create a new folder which will hold your theme. Let’s call it `MyTheme`.

Create two new folders in your theme folder – `layout` and `template`.

In the skin folder, open your theme folder and create folders – css, js, images.

[image] [image]

Next, you should create `local.xml` and place it in `layout` folder.

That’s all you need!

> Working with the theme

Next step would be to tell Magento which package and theme will be used as default.

To do this, go to

```
system > configuration > design
```

[image]

First, we need to tell Magento which package we will use. We are using `MyPackage` design package.

As you can see, we can use assets from multiple themes. Templates can be called from one theme, skin files from another. Yet another cool thing about Magento and its fallback system which will be explained in the next paragraph.

Now, insert your theme name in all fields except `default` field – leave that blank.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Can you please share the code with files in specific folder?

Comment: Need local.xml code.

Comment: In order to make this thing easy, first copy `base/default` theme with all folders, and copy it in your theme folder. After that do customization